# Unity New Input System Touch Menu - Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm making a Game with Touch, Controller and Keyboard Input with the NEW InputSystem 1.0.2

If the game is currently running and the StartButton will be pressed, then the TouchUI should disappear and PauseMenu should appear. Currently it shows me the error messages. This only happens in the TouchUICanvas environment. Works perfectly fine with gamepad and keyboard.

Everything works.

**ErrorWarnings: by pressing with Touch on the StartButton(TouchUICanvas)**

> -Assertionfailed UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0(NativeInputUpdateType,NativeInputEventBuffer*)
> UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate(NativeInputUpdateType,IntPtr)(at/Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/Input/Private/Input.cs:120)
>
> -ArgumentOutOfRangeExceptionduringeventprocessingofDynamicupdate;resettingeventbuffer
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0(NativeInputUpdateType,NativeInputEventBuffer*)
> UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate(NativeInputUpdateType,IntPtr)(at/Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/Input/Private/Input.cs:120)
>
> -ArgumentOutOfRangeException:Specifiedargumentwasoutoftherangeofvalidvalues.
> Parametername:index
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities.InlinedArray`1[TValue].get_Item(System.Int32index)(atLibrary/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0.2/InputSystem/Utilities/InlinedArray.cs:68)
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.DynamicBitfield.ClearBit(System.Int32bitIndex)(atLibrary/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0.2/InputSystem/Utilities/DynamicBitfield.cs:51)
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputManager.FireStateChangeNotifications(System.Int32deviceIndex,System.DoubleinternalTime,UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.InputEvent*eventPtr)(atLibrary/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0.2/InputSystem/InputManager.cs:2924)
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputManager.UpdateState(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputDevicedevice,UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.InputUpdateTypeupdateType,System.Void*statePtr,System.UInt32stateOffsetInDevice,System.UInt32stateSize,System.DoubleinternalTime,UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.InputEventPtreventPtr)(atLibrary/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0.2/InputSystem/InputManager.cs:3101)
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputManager.UpdateState(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputDevicedevice,UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.InputEvent*eventPtr,UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.InputUpdateTypeupdateType)(atLibrary/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0.2/InputSystem/InputManager.cs:3017)
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputManager.OnUpdate(UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.InputUpdateTypeupdateType,UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.InputEventBuffer&eventBuffer)(atLibrary/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0.2/InputSystem/InputManager.cs:2707)
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.NativeInputRuntime+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<set_onUpdate>b__0(UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputUpdateTypeupdateType,UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputEventBuffer*eventBufferPtr)(atLibrary/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0.2/InputSystem/NativeInputRuntime.cs:64)
> UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0(NativeInputUpdateType,NativeInputEventBuffer*)
> UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate(NativeInputUpdateType,IntPtr)(at/Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/Input/Private/Input.cs:120)

**These 2 Error-Codes Appeared after I pressed with Touch - on the ResumeButton(pauseScreen) with the function PauseUnpause().**

-Action has been triggered but apparently not from an interaction yet there's interactions on the binding that got triggered?!?

> UnityEngine.GameObject:SetActive(Boolean)
> OverworldPauseMenu:PauseUnpause() (at Assets/OverworldPauseMenu.cs:47)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at
> /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.15f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:377)
>
> -Control index out of range UnityEngine.GameObject:SetActive(Boolean) OverworldPauseMenu:PauseUnpause() (at Assets/OverworldPauseMenu.cs:47)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at
> /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.15f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:377)

**The code for the PauseMenu:**

```
public class OverworldPauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pauseScreen;
    public GameObject TouchUICanvas;
    public string mainMenu;
    public bool isPaused;
    ControlsSetup controls;
    public void Awake()
    {
        controls = new ControlsSetup();

        controls.SwitchPro.ButtonStart.performed += ctx => PauseUnpause();
    }
    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public void PauseUnpause()
    {
        if (isPaused)
        {
            isPaused = false;
            TouchUICanvas.SetActive(true);
            pauseScreen.SetActive(false);

            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }
        else
        {
            isPaused = true;
            TouchUICanvas.SetActive(false);
            pauseScreen.SetActive(true);

            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
    }
    public void MainMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(mainMenu);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
    void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.SwitchPro.Enable();
    }
    void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.SwitchPro.Disable();
    }
}
```

See relevant images below.

StartButton:

[image: StartButton]

Controls Setup:

[image: ControlsSetup]

Console ERROR:

[image: Console-ERROR]

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" this issue by delaying for one frame buttons gameobject disabling. A little bit hacky, but at least works for me.

Comment: I'll a bit to this as to why this bug occurs and why this solution "fixes" it. The reason this exception happens is because after an on-screen button simulates input device events, it disables the input device it just created. However, because the input system wasn't actually done processing the event in that same frame, it encounters an ArgumentOutOfRange error in the internal input system array when attempting to reach the device created by this on-screen button. By adding a small delay, you allow the Input System to reach to this simulated device and process the event before it's gone.